# check CORS is deployed for flask app deployed in kubernetes

Tags: python, docker, flask, kubernetes

I have flask code and I have enabled the CORS in it. I want to check which security headers it is passing or is it enabled.

How to check it, since it is deployed as service in kubernetes?

I have deployed the code as the service in K8s. I want to check security headers being passed by code when i submit a request

```
@app.route("/")
@cross_origin()
def helloWorld():
  return "Hello, cross-origin-world!"
```

In my view , it has nothing to do with code as my question is how to check if I enable the cors  but since it is asked by one of the expert, I am sharing yaml file similar to one I use. I have not defined anything related to cors here.

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
name: test-ingress
annotations:
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
rules:

- http:
  paths:

  - path: /testpath
    pathType: Prefix
    backend:
    serviceName: test
    servicePort: 80

Comment: did you check the logs of the pod running the flask server ?

Comment: Yes, I checked the logs but I cant see cors headers. How do you check logs like this kubectl logs my-pod  ??

Comment: yes , kubectl logs should give the error . I would suggest you to use https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/logging/  instead of default logging

Comment: okay, I am not getting any error. I need see the CORS is enabled , if yes. then which headers are being passed

Comment: Please give more details about k8s side, is it a service? ingress?

Comment: Please upvote the question I have added the details in it @KoopaKiller

Comment: @Coderun, please update the post with inforamtion about kubernetes side, for example, service yaml, ingress yaml, what ingress do you have? Did you enable cors in the ingress?

Comment: Yes, I am deploying the service yaml  defining port, image,vault. I didnt touch ingress yaml, what details should I add there to enable CORS

Comment: @Coderun Please see [this link](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#enable-cors). In Nginx-ingress you need to use an annotation to enable CORS. Please let me know it helps you, and please add in your post your ingress yaml spec in order to get a better helm from community.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to access an application exposed as a service from your local machine for debugging is port-forwad. Try `kubectl port-forward -h`. The relevant example is:

```
# Listen on ports 5000 and 6000 locally, forwarding data to/from ports 5000 and 6000 in a pod selected by the service
  kubectl port-forward service/myservice 5000 6000
```

You can specify source:target ports e.g. from 8080:5000 if you want to listen on 8080 on localhost but the service's port is 5000.

Then, you can access this via curl or a browser using `localhost:$port`. $port is either whatever you chose to listen on. If you service is not in the default namespace, you need to specify the namespace as well `-n mynamespace`.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to check if CORS is enabled or not

Comment: And checking the headers of a http request would tell you that.

Comment: In headers it is showing nothing even though I have added the CORS :(